# Django Bootstrap Crispy InlineField with custom validation missing message

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-crispy-forms

I'm using Django Crispy forms to render a fieldset containing multiple fields, most of which are not inline, but I have a date of birth field (a DateField with SelectDate Widget) which I'd like to be inline. It uses a custom validation in which is translates date to age and then checks that the user is over 18.

This validation is correct and works normally when the field is rendered in a FieldSet.

[image: working field]

However, after applying crispy_forms.bootstrap.InlineField, with no options, just simply:

```
 Layout(
        Fieldset(
            #Other fields...
            InlineField('dob'),
       )
 )
```

The message does not display - though validation still works:
[image: inline field with no validation]

How do I get this message to appear while using InlineField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InlineField doesn't support showing error from form.

Comment: So would you recommend adding validation in the clean() method of the form, or elsewhere?

Comment: If validation is working, then no need to add it manually. You just need to show error message. Use Form.errors to get a dictionary with errors and render them in the template. Here's a link from Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors